# Tilt Text for Roulette Wheel

Tags: text-object

I am quite new to Blender (since about 1 month).

I am now trying to build a roulette wheel for practice.
I am now facing the problem that I have to put the parts where the numbers are at an angle.
But if I do so, I can't make the numbers tilted in the same angle, so that it looks realistic.

I hope my explanation is understandable and someone can help me :)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: please show some pictures of what you want to achieve, where is the problem, etc...

Comment: I have now added some images, I hope they help. As you can see in my reference image (the first one) the part where the numbers are aren't flat. So is there ah way to move the parts where the numbers are together with the numbers? :)

Comment: I don't understand, I guess your numbers are an image and you unwrap your mesh so it aligns correctly, no? So the numbers don't have to be tilted, it's the mesh that needs to be tilted

Comment: I started with a circle and extruded and scaled it several times to get the basic shape of the wheel and then added in the numbers as a text object and rotated them. So every number is a text object. Is it a bad way to do it like that? And now I want to tilt the text objects together with the mesh. Do you know how I mean?

Comment: as the numbers appear flat you should create a picture (jpg or png) in photoshop with the numbers all around a circle, then unwrap this part of your roulette and align it to these numbers. I can give an illustrated explanation if needed

Comment: I think I know what you mean, but I think an illustrated explanation would be really helpful. Would be very nice if you could give me one :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So as your numbers are flat you should rather use an image texture than 3D meshes:

- Give colors to the different parts of your mesh (here red, black, and whatever for the rest).

[image]

- Unwrap the whole mesh.

[image]

- In the *UV Editor*, export the UV layout.

[image]

- Use this UV layout as a blueprint to create the numbers layout in an image editor. Keep a layer of white letters on a transparent background, save as PNG.

[image]

- Import the image in Blender's UV Editor, align the UV correctly.

[image]

- Go in the *Shader Editor*, select the red material, create an *Image Texture* node, plug it into a *Diffus*e, plug its *Alpha* into the Factor of a *Mix Shader*, plug the red *Diffuse* into the other socket of this mix. Do the same thing for the black material.

[image]

- The numbers should appear on the roulette.

[image]

Comment: Thank you very very much man :)